# How to decide where (in a thesis) a glossary should be positioned?

Tags: thesis, writing-style, glossary

I want to include a **glossary** in my **master’s thesis** explaining some technical terms.

My university doesn't make any specifications about the usage or position of glossaries. So I'm asking myself:

- Is it better to **put the glossary at the beginning of the thesis?** (e.g. between the Table of Contents and the main content) That way the reader would see it first and either read it or keep in mind that he can look up unfamiliar terms there. But it would disrupt the reading flow between Abstract, Table of Contents and Content.
- Or would it be better to but the **glossary in the appendix?** Maybe with footnotes refering to it, each time a new term is used for the first time.

The current structure of the thesis is:

```
- Titlepage
- Abstract
- Table of Contents
- [INSERT GLOSSARY HERE?]
- Main Content
   - Chapter A
   - Chapter B
   - ...
   - Chapter N
- Appendix
   - Appendix A
   - Appendix B
   - Table of Images
   - Table of Tables
   - Table of Literature
   - [INSERT GLOSSARY HERE?]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is utterly a matter of style. Just put it where it makes more sense to you. If you expect people actually NEED to read it before they can read your thesis, just put it in front. Otherwise, put it after the main text.

Comment: If somebody needs to read the glossary highly depends on the reader. My professor might need it. I'm only wondering if it might disrupt the flow of reading to much.

Comment: My thesis had a list of abbreviations and acronyms that came as part of the front matter. It was easier to define all of those things once at the beginning in the same place rather than worry if I need to redefine HMQC in chapter 4, when it hasn't been used since chapter 1.

Comment: In another guideline of my university (one about assignments in general) I just now found the instruction to put the glossary before the main text. So in my case the decision to have it at the front was the right one.

Answer (score 26):

I suggest to follow the order reported on [Wikipedia – Book design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design).

Here is the suggested order (skip all that is not needed in your thesis; colophons are only needed in published works, and your publisher will take care of them):

- front matter

  - title page
  - colophon
  - contents
  - foreword
  - preface
  - acknowledgment
  - introduction
  - dedication
  - prologue
- body matter

  - content – optionally divided into volumes, books, parts, chapters, sections
- back matter

  - epilogue
  - outro
  - afterword
  - conclusion
  - postscript
  - appendix
  - glossary
  - bibliography
  - index
  - colophon

Comment: Could you reproduce the essence of the wiki page here, this makes your post selfcontained, and not dependend on a non StackExchange external website.

Comment: I'm not sure if the wikipedia article on Book design in general is the perfect match for a thesis. Reading a piece of fiction like "Lord of the Rings" which is mentioned as instructive example in the article, is a whole different way of reading than reading a scientific work. So the best order of the contents might be different, too.

Comment: Good point. That list seems to be tailored to all kinds of publications, though: most works of fiction do not need a glossary, a bibliography and an index, so I would say that the authors had at least both fiction and non-fiction in mind. (that said, I wouldn't be surprised to find out that *LotR* contains all of them).

Comment: One element very specific to some kinds of academic theses are the included papers. Do they go all the way at the end of the back matter? What about the lists of papers, somewhere in the front matter? Would be nice to have a list more geared to this.

Comment: @gerrit List of papers included in the thesis should be either a part of Introduction, or go directly before it. If you include a "carbon-copy" of all the pepers in the thesis, I suggest putting them after everything else. They form a completely non-intergal part of the thesis, they have their own title, list of authors, references etc.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni In novel books which contain just one novel, the table of contents is typically in the back-matter (since you want to open the book and simply read it; you use the ToC only if you lose your bookmark). If it contains a small number of them, the short ToC only with their titles is in the front-matter (since you want the reader to choose one prior reading) and the full ToC with the chapter titles is in the back-matter (reason as above). However, this is a typical setting, not a strong rule. Still, it shows that in belletry, the rules are quite different.

Answer (score 8):

Put the glossary **after any appendices and before the index**.

**EDIT:** This advice is simply based on a very quick survey of the textbooks that I had close to hand. The sample size is therefore small, possibly subject biased (physics, mathematics, astronomy, economics), and therefore subject to argument. Thanks to aeismail for the comment prompting this edit.

Comment: Just curious—is there a specific reason why it should be there?

Comment: Aside from any over-riding requirements set by a departmental style guide (and we're told that there is none in this case), placing the glossary at the end of the document in general seems to correspond with the trend that I see in the textbooks that I use. Conformity with established trends isn't necessarily a good thing, I realise.

Comment: You should put that in your answer (I should have mentioned that in my original comment; the goal was to avoid a "quick-fire" answer that doesn't explain things to future readers).

Comment: Nicholas, if I understand you correctly the reason for your advice is, that most people do it that way. Is that what you meant?

Comment: For background information: There is a style guide, but it doesn't say anything about the use of glossaries.

Comment: @aeismail: Thanks for your comments prompting my edit.

Comment: @Karin: Yes, but see the qualification that I included in my edit.

Comment: @aeismail See my answer for the reasoning.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers already contain the conclusions of my answer. However, I'll try to give some reasoning behind.

- **Glossary, Nomenclature, List of Symbols, Index, References, etc.** -- all these are *indexes*, and should go to the backmatter.
- **Table of Contents, List of Figures, etc.** -- these specify the *contents*, and should go to the frontmatter.

The difference is that *indexes* are have in general logical sorting of some type (alphabetical or other), whereas the *contents* strictly reflect the order of the text in the document.

As for the order of them: *the more used* they are, *the farer away from the mainmatter* they go (i.e. first in frontmatter and last in backmatter). This depends a lot on your reader. The reason for this is that the closer to the cover they are, the easier it is to reach them. In general, the most used index in a thesis are the references, so they go last. In textbooks, the General index goes last, since it's more interesting for the reader.

The rule above is, on the other hand, less important than the fact that **Title, half-title, dedication, preface and colophon** have priority, and are obviously the outer-most elements of the work.

So, in the end, you might get to this order:

```
FRONTMATTER
  Title
  Half-title
  Dedicatory
  Preface

  Table of Contents
  other "Contents"

MAINMATTER

BACKMATTER
  Appendicies
  Various indexes (Glossary, Nomenclature, ...)
  References / Bibliography
  Colophon (if placed in backmatter; it can go before
     half-title on the verso page as well)
```

In the end, *none* of these rules is very strict.

Comment: Interesting reasoning. Especially the part `the closer to the cover, the easier to reach`. Personally I wouldn't feel to comfortable putting something like the list of figures or list of tables before the main content. I don't want to force all readers to thumb through something they might not need, before they can start reading.

Comment: @kdzia The point is: How many people are actually going to read the thesis from the very beginning to the very end? Not many I think, and each of them will need to find Chapter 1 exactly once (when they start reading). So it doesn't matter whether you have two or three more sheets of paper before the actual Chapter 1 or not.

Comment: I think it does matter. If the majority of the readers are interested in reading the titlepage, the abstract, the TOC and in skimming through the chapters, the thesis should be optimized for that. The few who want to read the table of images and table of tables before the main content will have to go to the backmatter for that.

Answer (score 1):

A glossary in the front before the main body has less context and disrupts the flow -- people want to read the body, not get to a list of definitions first. I attended an editorial seminar once and the instructors recounted anecdotes of leading tech companies who requested user studies on  content placement like LOT, LOF, TOC, glossaries, and so on. The verdict: Just give me the content first and make it lean.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Do you happen to have any references to the user studies you're mentioning? That would be very interresting.